# Google Maps Autocomplete (destroy and reuse)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have a web application that utilizes the Google Maps Javascript API.

One of the things that I want to be able to do is to 'filter' out results.

Currently, I have 4 buttons (All, State, City, Zip).

When the All button is pressed, there are no filters and the googleMaps options is only

`var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};`

When I have the City button pressed, I want to be able to run the

`autocomplete.setTypes(['(cities)'])` and have only cities show up for that session.

This is the code that I have, I have been trying to search for other places but have not found anything just yet. Thank you for the help in advanced!

```
var input        = document.getElementById(this.$refs.geography_search.id);
var options      = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
if (!place.geometry) {
    window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
    }
});

if (this.buttonActivated == 'city') {
     google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(autocomplete);
     autocomplete.setTypes(['(cities)']);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm guessing that @Ben wants to destroy the `autocomplete` instance and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

**simply remove and insert input element for destroy google autocomplete**

```
var location_search_input = $( ".search_input_container" ).html();

$( ".search_input_container" ).html( '' );

$( ".search_input_container" ).html( location_search_input);
```

**Here Is Full Code..,**

*This will help you..,*

```
function initAutocomplete() {

    jQuery( document ).ready( function($){ 

        $('.type_of_search').selecter();

        var location_search_input = $( ".search_input_container" ).html();

        $(".type_of_search").change( function(){

            if( $( this ).val() == "name" ) {

                $( ".search_input_container" ).html( '' );
                $( ".search_input_container" ).html( location_search_input );

            } else {

                     function fillInAddress() {

                            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                            var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
                            console.log(lat);
                            var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
                            console.log(lng);
                            document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat;
                            document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng;
                      }

                      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
                      var componentForm = {
                        street_number: 'short_name',
                        route: 'long_name',
                        locality: 'long_name',
                        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
                        country: 'long_name',
                        postal_code: 'short_name'
                      };

                        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete_1')),
                            {types: ['geocode']});

                        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
                        // fields in the form.
                        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
                 }

        } ).change(); 

    });


}
```